# declaring powershell variable

Tags: variables, powershell

Why doesn't the variable declaration below get retained?

```
$LogonStatus = change logon /query
```

I get a response when this is declared but the output value isn't getting retained in the variable.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your problem, can you possibly try expanding the question with input, output and expected output?

Comment: I't might be out of scope, depending on where you declared it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325569/variable-scoping-in-powershell) for a short explantion on scopes, or [the full technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you got downvoted...this was easily testable.

The problem is that the output from that command is not being sent to stdout

Do this to capture all output streams

```
 $test = change logon /query *>&1
```

It looks like it returns in error stream. To filter it down to just the data you want, you can do this:

```
$Test = (change logon /query *>&1) | Select-String "Session.*$"
```