# Powershell scoping change?

Tags: arrays, powershell, scoping

I've been having an issue with updating a global variable in a function.  I found the following article, which looked promising:

[Variable scoping in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325569/variable-scoping-in-powershell)

However, I discovered that nothing he posted matched the output I saw.  Here's his code:

```
$array=@("g")
function foo()
{
    $array += "h"
    Write-Host $array
}

& {
    $array +="s"
    Write-Host $array
}
foo

Write-Host $array
```

And his results:

```
g s
g h
g
```

However... My results on PowerShell 5.0 are:

```
s
h
g
```

Adding the suggested solution of `$global:array += "s"` gives:

```
g
h
g
```

What am I missing and how do I rectify it?  How can I update a variable that is outside of a function from within a function if $global: doesn't work?

Comment: Side note:  In ISE, I get the expected result.  But when running it from my .ps1, I get the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array is declared at `script` scope, not global. Either declare the array as a global variable as well:

```
$global:array=@("g")
```

or use script scope to update it:

```
$script:array += "h"
```

I'd suggest the latter because using global variables for things only your script needs is a bit superfluous.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was missing.... the declaration had to be added as $global: as well in order for it to work.  I also agree that scoping to $script: is a much better overall option and worked as expected in my actual PS script.  Thanks!