# Powershell Assigning and Retrieving Variables

Tags: powershell, variables

So I have been battling all day with Powershell.  I'm trying to make something like I put down here. I declare a Variable in the beginning of the script, then I declare 2 functions. One function sets a value to the variable, and the other gets the variable.

When getting the variable I get nothing - it's empty.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong (I'm guessing something little and stupid)

```
$ImUsedInMultplePlaces = ""

Function LetsChooseSomething
{
    Write-Host "1: something"
    Write-Host "2: Something else"
    $answer = Read-Host "Pick One"

    switch($answer)
    {
        "1" { $ImUsedInMultiplePlaces = "We chose something!"; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
        "2" { $ImUsedInMultiplePlaces = "We chose something else!"; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
    }
}

Function ShowMeMyChoice
{
    Write-Host $ImUsedInMultiplePlaces
}

Write-Host "Welcome to this amazing script, im about to make you choose"
Write-Host ""
LetsChooseSomething

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Great Choice!"
Write-Host ""

ShowMeMyChoice
```

Comment: Read about scoping: [Variable scoping in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9325569) and [the official docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question of [scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847849.aspx). Replace with these and give it a go.

```
    "1" { $global:ImUsedInMultiplePlaces = "We chose something!"; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
    "2" { $global:ImUsedInMultiplePlaces = "We chose something else!"; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.. Thanks alot!  Wasted a lot of time on this one   (yes it worked now)

Answer (score 1):

The use of global variables makes software harder to read and understand. Since any code anywhere in the program can change the value of the variable at any time, understanding the use of the variable may entail understanding a large portion of the program. Global variables make separating code into reusable libraries more difficult. They can lead to problems of naming because a global variable defined in one file may conflict with the same name used for a global variable in another file (thus causing linking to fail). A local variable of the same name can shield the global variable from access, again leading to harder-to-understand code. The setting of a global variable can create side effects that are hard to locate and predict. The use of global variables makes it more difficult to isolate units of code for purposes of unit testing; thus they can directly contribute to lowering the quality of the code.

I renamed (and modified) the functions slightly, aiming for more clarity.

The first function outputs a string:

```
function Select-Something
{
    Write-Host "1: Something"
    Write-Host "2: Something else"
    $answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Pick One"

    switch($answer)
    {
        "1" { [string]$output = "We chose something!"     ; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
        "2" { [string]$output = "We chose something else!"; Write-Host "I put it in there!"  }
    }

    return $output
}
```

By adding a ([string]) parameter to the second function it is able to accept any string:

```
function Show-Selection ([string]$Selection)
{
    Write-Host $Selection
}
```

As you can see, it makes the code easier to read:

```
Write-Host "Welcome to this amazing script, I'm about to make you choose."
Write-Host ""

$choice = Select-Something

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Great Choice!"
Write-Host ""

Show-Selection $choice
```