# How to retrieve a variable value from a script block (job)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the value of a variable modified inside a scriptblock:

```
function Test-Function {
    $var = "apple"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        $var = "banana"
    }
    Write-Host "Variable is $var"
}
Test-Function
Variable is: apple
```

I am trying to get the output 'banana'. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable scoping in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325569/variable-scoping-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using PS Jobs in your code, you need to use wait for the job to get completed using `wait-job` and finally you have to receive the job using `receive-job`. Replace your code with the below:

```
function Test-Function {
    $var = "apple"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        $var = "banana"
        Write-Host "Variable is $var"
    } | Wait-Job -Any |Receive-Job

    #Write-Host "Variable is $var"
}
Test-Function
```

Hope it helps.